# SATA RAID 0 (striping) configuration under Windows 11

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, windows-11, raid

I have a 'semi-newish' desktop I put together (GigaByte motherboard) with 2x M.2 500GB SSDs. I thought I had properly configured them in RAID 0 via the UEFI settings. Yet then today I was adding a third drive and had to wipe it with `diskpart` and I noticed the following:

[image]

It would be disk 1 and 2 we're talking about. I never saw it come on online, so I sort of just presumed it was configured correctly.

Quite obviously though I missed something. What ought I do from the Windows side to get this configured correctly (beyond initializing the disk)? And can I still do that this late in the game? (i.e. Disk 1 obviously already has data on it).

Comment: what are you asking exactly?